# How to put error messages inside a Prestashop 1.7 inside form box?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I'm creating a recaptcha module to front office, all code is ok, but the error message is going to wrong place.

I'm using the Prestashop 1.7.6.1, the error message is printing on top of front office, and I need the error message to print inside form box.

I'm set the error message like this:
modules/recaptcha/recaptcha.php

```php
public function hookActionRecaptchaAccountValidation()
{
    if (!$this->isValidateRecaptcha()) { // Logic to validate recaptcha
        // Set my error message
        $context->controller->errors[] = $this->l('It was not possible to validate the reCaptcha.');
    }
}
```

I'm overriding AuthController to execute my custom hook that will make recaptcha validation logic, here is ok, I put this code too, case you need.

```php
class AuthController extends AuthControllerCore
{
    public function initContent()
    {
        if(Tools::isSubmit('submitLogin')){
            // Execute my custom hook
            Hook::exec('actionRecaptchaAccountValidation');

            if(sizeof($this->context->controller->errors)){ // Verify if has error message
                $login_form = $this->makeLoginForm()->fillWith(
                    Tools::getAllValues()
                );    
                $this->context->smarty->assign([
                    'login_form' => $login_form->getProxy(),
                ]);
                $this->setTemplate('customer/authentication');
                FrontController::initContent();
                return;
            }
        }

        parent::initContent();
    }
}
```

...So, how can I put the error message inside form box like this example?

Please, check this image, where I show exactly what I need.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hgPF.png

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better look into `CustomerLoginForm` class and consider to override it. The `submit` method may be exactly what you are looking for. Just add one more validation and define your error with `$this->errors[''][]` construction

Comment: Thank you for reply, so I've seen that class, so I thought if doing this was the best way, I mean, overriding a class just to insert a error message in CustomerLoginForm->errors... I thought another thing too, I thought to insert this error message in my overriding class AuthController using $login_form->errors, but the problem is CustomerLoginForm->errors is private... =/ Do you know if overriding CustomerLoginForm is a good practice or if there is another way more simple and functional?

Comment: 2 days ago I found an article doing something like that: $this->context->controller->errors['hooks_fieldname'][] = 'Error message!'; But I tried it and doesn't work to me... I searched this article right now, but I can't find it. If I find again I post here.

Comment: I found another article that comments about what I said above, but I not sure if this is specific to back-office, and the article example is message to a field... https://webkul.com/blog/display-custom-error-on-symfony-admin-product-controller-form-in-prestashop-1-7/